# AsyncLocal Serilog LogContext in Blazor Server Middleware

Tags: c#, middleware, blazor-server-side, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I create a custom Middliware to Push info about HttpContext into my Serilog LogContext:

```
if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

string profile = context.Request.Host.Host;
string ipAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
string userAgent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

using (LogContext.PushProperty("Profile", profile))
using (LogContext.PushProperty("IpAddress", ipAddress))
using (LogContext.PushProperty("UserAgent", userAgent))
{
  await _next(context);
}
```

I want to understand the behavior of my LogContext properties in various queries (Hhtp Requests).

From Microsoft Docs:

> AsyncLocal Represents ambient data that is local to a given asynchronous control flow, such as an asynchronous method.

What is my asynchronous control flow in Blazor Server Middleware?

Answer (score 0):

> What is my asynchronous control flow

The `AsyncLocal<T>` values persist for the entirety of `await _next(context)`; i.e., until `_next` completes. In all modern middleware systems, this is all the middleware following the current one.

Comment: If AsyncLocals values persist for the entirety of all the middleware and each HttpRequest will have its own AsyncLocals, but how AsyncLocals values (set at my middleware) flows into Razor component or into unhandled exception in Blazor Server app? Because Blazor Server uses SignalR for communication between the client and the server, and I wanted to know how my razor component get AsyncLocal Context if button click in Blazor doesn't trigger HttpRequest?

Comment: @dotnetdev I don't have much experience with Blazor, but I would be surprised if they did cross a process boundary. Is that what you observe?

Comment: exactly no, and that is why I wanted to know how it works

Comment: @dotnetdev: Yes, don't expect it to transfer process boundaries. Occasionally there is special support for *specific* async locals, such as activity ids, but I wouldn't expect any transfer of your own async locals.